# How to add only specific markers on bottom axis using TeeChart?

Tags: .net, teechart

I just started with TeeChart. I have a requirement based on which I need to mark only those points on bottom axis which corresponds to a data point to be plotted on the graph. I do not need a completed series with a pre-defined max and min value range and a pre-defined increment to be used as a marked on bottom axis. I need to achieve something like this.[image]

Comment: Is there any way this could be achieved using TeeChart. I have gone through the documentation related to axes, but I couldn't find anything that might help in this regard.

Comment: Please add some tag to identify your programming environment

Comment: I am working with .NET version of this control. Added the tag

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (VCL):

```
Chart1.Axes.Bottom.LabelStyle:=talPointValue;
```

Comment: Is it the same in .NET version also? Would I be able to mark random points that I may require on Bottom Axis with it?